# GUI programming study materials?

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, pyqt, graphical-programming

Found the GUI programming bit difficult to grasp. Looking for some good materials/books/lecture_videos/advice for learning this. I am interseted in learning Java(swing),Qt, pyQt....

Comment: It would probably benefit you to pick one library and concentrate on it, rather than trying to learn them all at once.

Comment: Looking to study anyone only. It would be nice if you give me more info about anyone of these

Comment: Google and Wikipedia are down?  Pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked any of the online documentations [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials.html)?

Comment: Checked and tried QT. Looking for some materials that handles from a real project perspective. Some material that clearly explains form start to end

Answer (score 0):

Pick any one of these, download the SDK, build the default gui application (just an empty window, typically), and then keep adding buttons, input fields, etc. until you can do what you want to do.  Appeal to the demos and documentation as need be.  I can only speak from experience regarding Qt, which I have found (as an indie coder) to be fantastic in every way.  Rich demos and excellent documentation, a good form designer.